# How to prevent the flickering associated with addChild in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have the following application where I'm loading the labels dynamically at run-time and I need them to update every X seconds (3 here in the example). What is the best way to prevent the flickering associated with removing the children and then re-adding the children during an update on a very slow internet connection? I would like this to be seamless.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            width="100%" height="100%" 
            creationComplete="init()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.containers.HBox;
        import mx.controls.Button;
        import mx.controls.Label;

        private var timer:Timer;

        protected function init():void
        {
            updateContainer();
            timer = new Timer(3000);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateContainer);
            timer.start();
        }

        private function updateContainer(evt:TimerEvent = null):void
        {
            trace("update");
            container.removeAllChildren();

            for(var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++){
                var myHBox:HBox = new HBox();
                myHBox.percentWidth = 100;
                myHBox.setStyle("backgroundColor", "#FFFFFF");
                var myLabel:Label = new Label();
                myLabel.text = "Hello World " + i;

                myHBox.addChild(myLabel);
                container.addChild(myHBox);
            }
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>    

<mx:VBox id="container" />

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Note that I already tried encapsulating them in another container and then trying to add the entire container as a whole instead of adding them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that it is not guaranteed that you can do your operation (*"remove all elements"* and *"add the new children"*) in one update. In fact, it is absolutely sure that they will happen in at least two updates - one for the removal, and one for the addition. The flickering is caused by the brief time frame between the two updates.

The easiest fix is to reuse the already created components instead of the laborious creation of 50 containers with labels on every timer update. With some more effort you may create and remove the new components dynamically or use bindings.

Here is a quick modification of your code with component reuse. You won't experience flickering here, as the labels are changed in just one update.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           creationComplete="init()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.containers.HBox;
        import mx.controls.Button;
        import mx.controls.Label;

        private var timer:Timer;
        private var labels:Array = [];

        protected function init():void
        {
            updateContainer();
            timer = new Timer(1000);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateContainer);
            timer.start();
            initContainers();
        }

        private function initContainers():void
        {
            labels = [];
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                var myHBox:HBox = new HBox();
                myHBox.percentWidth = 100;
                myHBox.setStyle("backgroundColor", "#FFFFFF");
                var myLabel:Label = new Label();
                myHBox.addChild(myLabel);
                container.addChild(myHBox);
                labels.push(myLabel);
            }
        }

        private function updateContainer(evt:TimerEvent = null):void
        {
            trace("update");

            for(var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                if (labels[i] != null)
                {
                    (labels[i] as Label).text = "Hello World " + i + " " + (new Date).time;
                }
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:VBox id="container" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this was eventually what I went with.